# vue 2 vue-router mode history infinite loop

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I want to use history mode with vue-router and Vue 2 in order to get rid of the # in the URL.
When I add mode: 'history' to my router, my page loops.
I believe my problem has something to do with not adding 'a simple catch-all fallback route to the server'.  I have read the vue-router documentation and tried suggested solutions with no success.
I am just trying to get the devServer to work for now.

router set up:

```
export default new Router({
  mode: 'history',
  devServer: { historyApiFallback: true },
  base: appConfig.buildDriveUiSubDirPath(""),...
```

vue.config.js dev server set up:

```
module.exports = {
    publicPath: appConfig.buildDriveUiSubDirPath("/"),
    devServer: {
        disableHostCheck: true,...
```

When I remove mode: 'history', from the router constructor the page works without looping.

Comment: What documentation have you been reading?  There isn't a `new Router()` constructor and I see nothing in the API for a `devServer` option or `historyApiFallback` property.  These look like [webpack settings](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserverhistoryapifallback) which is decidedly different thing than Vue Router.  Here is the [Vue Router v3 documentions](https://v3.router.vuejs.org/guide/) (the version I assume you're using since you're using Vue 2). Check that your code matches the official documentation.